# How to set custom DHCP option in dhcp request in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, dhcp

DHCP client in Windows XP has built in options.

One of them is `Requested IP Address`.

How  to set custom IP address into that field?

Background:

In my local network there is DHCP server that responds to DHCP request only if valid `Requested IP Address` is specified. If it's not then I have no response for request.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do in a little more detail?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  More detail please?

Comment: So you want to control the IP address that your PC asks for in order to keep it the same as last time as much as possible?  This is the opposite way around from the way DHCP works, and should be set as a static in the dhcp server configuration.  Do you have access to the dhcp server?

Comment: Like charlie said, how or what for.  We have changed the home/intranet IP address range before in the registry. just search the registry for the IP address numbers, and change them. dont know if that helps.